# ZMQ ZAP connection problem in ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, python, firewall

I'm using python and ZMQ to publish and subscribe data through a TCP network connection. I tried to connect in normal mode (without ZAP) and ZAP mode which is an authentication protocol.

I've tried it by three Ubuntu 18.04 servers and the results are as below:

- I can send and receive packets by all servers in normal mode.
- In ZAP mode server one and two just have right connection, yet the third server is not able to communicate with others or vise versa.

All of the servers have the same configurations and **my question is that is there any specific configuration that would be effective in Ubuntu network connection like a firewall?** I want to add that I have checked the firewall and it is disabled.